# Remove unordered duplicates from sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the one below.

```
id1 id2
1   2
1   3
2   1
1   3
```

I want to remove duplicates from this table where rows having interchanged values of the two attributes are also considered to be duplicated.

The result should look like one of these. (Row order is irrelevant of course.)

```
id1 id2
1   2
1   3
```

or

```
id1 id2
1   3
2   1
```

I couldn't find a way to do this. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What result set do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited my question.

Comment: So id1=1, id2=2 needs to be considered a duplicate of id1=2, id2=1?

Comment: Yes, i want them to be. @brae

Comment: How can there be two expected resultsets iam wondering..

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to delete them?

Comment: @Strawberry The results have to be displayed and it isn't nice to show redundant data to, say users.

Comment: Well, there's all sorts of ways to control which data users have access to - but if that's what you want to do...

Comment: It's an assignment. :l @Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it using `union all`.

```
select distinct id1,id2
from tbl 
where id1 <= id2
union all
select distinct id1,id2
from tbl t1
where id1 > id2
and not exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t1.id1=t2.id2 and t1.id2=t2.id1)
```

For MySQL version 8 and later, you can simplify this solution to use `row_number` in conjunction with `least` and `greatest`.

```
select id1,id2
from (select id1,id2
      ,row_number() over(partition by least(id1,id2),greatest(id1,id2) 
                         order by id1) as rnum
      from tbl
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: i assume `where id1 <= id2` should be `where id1 < id2` instead?

Comment: if it is just `<` cases where both the id's are same will miss out.

Comment: "if it is just < cases where both the id's are same will miss out." True in that case shoudn't the second query also need to use `>=` instead off `>`

Comment: Nvm about my previous comment. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       GREATEST(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS Col1,
       LEAST(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS COl2
  FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: It does the job. Personally, I like the elegance of your solution.

Comment: this *might* generate rows which aren't in the table.

Comment: It doesn't match either result set shown, but if keeping ID1 & ID2 in the same order does not matter, then this is perfect.

Comment: @dandarc You're right. Thanks for pointing it out. In my case though, the order is not important.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Not disagreeing, but how so?

Comment: imagine the table had `(1,10)` and not `(10,1)`..this would output `(10,1)`, which doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I see what you're saying, good point. I originally thought you were saying it could result in pairs that weren't in the input and got a bit spooked. I was just assuming order of the columns didn't matter.

Comment: @frederick99 If you wanted, it would be quite nice to construct a query that was a hybrid of this answer and the accepted, so an elegant query that was guaranteed to return only rows that actually existed.